# How to change values to varying amount of asterisks according to several thresholds, and why asterisks were treated as number?

Tags: r, numbers, symbols

## 1. How to change values to varying amount of asterisks according to several thresholds

## 2. Why asterisks were treated as number?

---

#### Firstly, define a function to coerce all non-numeric values to NAs

```
# defined function
as_numeric <- function(x, na_string = c("NA", "na")){
    stopifnot(is.character(x) | is.numeric(x))
    NAs <- x %in% na_string
    x[NAs] <- "-9999"
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    x[NAs] <- NA_real_
    return(x)
}
```

#### The treated data works fine

```
a <- c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, "1", "NA", "A", 1i)
b <- as_numeric(a)
# [1] 0.001 0.010 0.050 0.100 1.000    NA    NA    NA
```

#### Problem occured when changing values smaller than `0.001` to `***`

##### Why the `*` and `**` previously assigned were treated as number as well?

```
# Change numbers to asterisk according to several conditions
b[b > 0.05] <- "ns"
b[b > 0.01 & b <= 0.05] <- "*"
b[b > 0.001 & b <= 0.01] <- "**"  # Until this line, everything works fine
b[b <= 0.001] <- "***"  # This line goes wrong

print(a)
# [1] "0.001" "0.01"  "0.05"  "0.1"   "1"     "NA"    "A"     "0+1i" 
print(b)
# [1] "***" "***" "***" "ns"  "ns"  NA    NA    NA   

# The correct answer should be
# # [1] "***" "**" "*" "ns"  "ns"  NA    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think the base R `as.numeric` would turn non-numeric characters into `NA` by default, so I'm not sure if it's necessary to build your own function for it.

```r
a <- c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, "1", "NA", "A", 1i)
b <- as.numeric(a)             
#> Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
[1] 0.001 0.010 0.050 0.100 1.000    NA    NA    NA
```

Second, in your approach, as soon as you assign "ns" to `b`, it immediately becomes a character vector instead of numeric. When you again assign "*" back to `b`, your third and fourth expressions would also take the "*" into consideration, which is a character. Therefore, I think you're looking for the `dplyr::case_when` function.

#### Dplyr::case_when

```r
library(dplyr)

case_when(b > 0.05 ~ "ns",
          b > 0.01 & b <= 0.05 ~ "*",
          b > 0.001 & b <= 0.01 ~ "**",
          b <= 0.001 ~ "***")
#> [1] "***" "**"  "*"   "ns"  "ns"  NA    NA    NA
```

#### Base R ifelse

```r
ifelse(b > 0.05, "ns", ifelse(b > 0.01 & b <= 0.05, "*", ifelse(b > 0.001 & b <= 0.01, "**", ifelse(b <= 0.001, "***", NA))))
[1] "***" "**"  "*"   "ns"  "ns"  NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I wonder if it is possible to use base R only?

Comment: @AlpacaKing Yes, I added a nested `ifelse` approach, which is solely base R

Comment: Thank you. One more question. Why the first three lines work well, only the fourth line `b[b <= 0.001] <- "***"` goes wrong?

Comment: @AlpacaKing Because "\*" is a character, when we're doing logical comparison on it, it's somehow treated as `FALSE`, which is zero, therefore zero would satisfy the condition in `b <= 0.001` and as a result, "\*\*\*" would replace the previous asterisks (I have to admit I'm not sure if it's the most accurate explanation, just playing around with `aaa <- c("*", "**", "***"); aaa > -0.00001 & aaa < 0.00001; aaa == 0`)